# Laravel 8: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8

I have two tables at db, one of them is named `users` which simply contains user information of website and the other one is `tags` which contains some hashtags that users can choose from them.

I also created a table named `tag_user` that can store the `tag_id` and `user_id` like this image:

[image]

(just like Stackoverflow that a user can select multiple tags such as *php*, *javascript* & etc)

So in order to make this relationship between these two, I added this to `User` model:

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

And also this one to `Tag` model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
```

And here is the select option on blade, and users can select multiple tags from db:

```
<select class="form-control BSinaBold" name="skills[]" id="skills" multiple>
    @foreach(\App\Models\Tag::all() as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}" {{ in_array($tag->id , Auth::user()->tags->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $tag->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Now as soon as I load the blade, I got this as error:

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.user_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select `users`.*, `user_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id` from `users` inner join `user_user` on `users`.`id` = `user_user`.`user_id` where `user_user`.`user_id` = 4)**

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

And here is also the migration of `tags` & `tag_user` table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('label');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('tag_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['tag_id','user_id']);
        });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to switch the class names around in the hasMany. Right now, in User, tags is saying that there are multiple users for each user, and Tags says there are multiple tags for each tag. The hasMany needs to reference the class it has many of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @aynber described in the comments:

In `User` model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

And in `Tag` model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```